# How can I remove an item from a dropdown menu only for a specific date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm working on a booking system project and I have a form that the user can fill out, with a date picker using react-datepicker and a dropdown menu with times that the users can select from. These times are fetched from a firestore database. The times collection looks like this:
[times collection in firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK9gj.jpg). And the form information collection looks like this: [form-info collection in firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GyLV.png).

So when a person selects a time for a specific date, I want to remove that time from the database only for that specific date so that users can still book that same time for another date. Here is what my code looks like:

```
function GThirtyminsp() {
  // Form values
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [team, setTeam] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [time, setTime] = useState(null);

  // To show times on screen
  const [times, setTimes] = useState([]);

  const timesRef = collection(db, "30min-goalie-semiprivate-times");
  const formRef = collection(db, "30min-goalie-semiprivate");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const timeData = await getDocs(timesRef);
      setTimes(timeData.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const createBooking = async () => {
    await addDoc(formRef, {
      name: name,
      date: date,
      email: email,
      number: number,
      team: team,
      age: age,
      time: time,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    createBooking();

    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setDate(null);
    setNumber("");
    setTeam("");
    setTime(null);
    setAge("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-3xl w-full text-center pt-10 font-bold">
        Book 30min Semi-Private Goalie Clinic
      </h1>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} class="flex flex-col pt-10 w-3/4">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="number"
            placeholder="Phone Number"
            value={number}
            onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="team"
            placeholder="Team Name"
            value={team}
            onChange={(e) => setTeam(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="age"
            placeholder="Age"
            value={age}
            onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <h2 class="text-center text-xl py-5 font-bold">
            Pick a Date and Time
          </h2>
          <div class="pb-10">
            <DatePicker
              className="border-2 p-3 w-full border-gray rounded-lg"
              selected={date}
              onChange={(date) => setDate(date)}
              placeholderText="Select a Date"
            />
            <div class="pt-10">
              <select onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}>
                {times.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <option key={item} value={item.time}>
                      {item.time}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button
            type="submit"
            class="bg-accent text-white font-semibold p-3 rounded-full"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that when the time is successfully booked, the time document gets deleted from the firebase firestore.

You can await the createBooking and if successful you then call the deletedoc, using the `time` state as the reference.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

Just make sure to validate that the booking was/is successful. Once you have this in-place you will want to reverse the process and add the doc if someone wants to cancel the booking.

Edit: example.

```
Const deleted= (time) =>{ await deleteDoc(doc(db, "30minute-inprivate etc", (time)
));
}
```

Comment: But wouldn’t this delete the time for all dates? I just want to delete the time for that specific date in the booking.

Comment: No, you are deleting the document, not the collection. I.e. you would reference the specific document, within the collection and delete the specific document.

Comment: Ok so thanks to you the deleting logic works but when the time is deleted, it gets deleted for all of the dates for some reason. did you take a look at my collections and documents in the firestore database? I think the problem is because of the way I have it set up.

Comment: const deleteTime = async (time) => {
    const timeDoc = doc(db, "30min-goalie-semiprivate-times", time);
    await deleteDoc(timeDoc);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await createBooking();
    deleteTime(time);

    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setDate(null);
    setNumber("");
    setTeam("");
    setTime(null);
    setAge("");
  };    (THIS IS HOW MY CODE LOOKS LIKE)

Comment: Do both collections have the same name? I can only see two collections.

Comment: do you have discord or something? If you can help me out with this I can offer something in return